# BOOST Functions? Where are they?

Tags: c++

how can I view the functions for the classes of the BOOST c++ library? I can't find them.....and I don't how I'd use anything from them if I don't know what I can use....

Comment: Are http://www.cplusplus.com and http://cppreference.com not enough?

Answer (score 2):

For STL there is http://www.cplusplus.com/

and example for STL vector:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

for boost there is http://www.boost.org/doc

an example for boost vector

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/container/vector.html